# How can i avoid getting argument errors?

Tags: ruby, arguments, calculation

i'm super new to ruby and i've been struggling with a problem in my code for hours which i don't seem to understand at all. When i execute the program, the output of the program says

```
./denem2.rb:1:in `ideal_weight': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
        from ./denem2.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

It's an extremely basic program that calculates the ideal weight for given parameters such "height" and "gender"

```
def ideal_weight(height, gender) # Ideal weight calculation
   if gender == "E" 
      ideal_weight = (height - 100) - (height - 150) / 4
   elsif gender == "K"
      ideal_weight = (height - 100) - (height - 150) / 2
   end
end 

puts "Please enter your height, weight and gender..."
height, weight, gender = gets.chomp.split
height = height.to_i
weight = weight.to_i
ideal_weight(height, gender)

if ideal_weight < weight
    puts "obese"
elsif ideal_weight == weight
    puts "ideal"
elsif ideal_weight > weight
    puts "light"
end
```

What i expected was that when i input the height and gender parameters, i should get a statement that says
things like "you're obese" or "you're in ideal state" or "you're light"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't meet the guidelines because it's caused by a syntax error that Ruby is explaining to you in the error message: you didn't give it enough parameters ("arguments") on line 15. Your method requires two parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You define a method with the name `ideal_weight`, but then you use it in the `if-elsif-else` block as a variable. You need to store the result of the method call first.

In ruby it is not necessary to use brackets for a method call. Try for instance

```ruby
puts 'Hello World'
puts('Hello World')
```

Now `if ideal_weight < weight` is interpreted as `if ideal_weight() < weight`, but the method takes two mandatory arguments. Moreover, you are having a method and a variable name of the same name. The interpreter does not know what to do/call in that case. You should find another name for the variable (or the method).

---

Working example

```ruby
def ideal_weight(height, gender) # Ideal weight calculation
   if gender == "E" 
      return (height - 100) - (height - 150) / 4
   elsif gender == "K"
      return (height - 100) - (height - 150) / 2
   end
end 

puts "Please enter your height, weight and gender..."
height, weight, gender = gets.chomp.split
height = height.to_i
weight = weight.to_i
ideal = ideal_weight(height, gender)

if ideal < weight
    puts "obese"
elsif ideal == weight
    puts "ideal"
elsif ideal > weight
    puts "light"
end
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering that made a lot of sense.

Comment: Happy to help. If that solved your issue, please accept the answer or refine your question. ;)

Comment: Please note there is no need to actually use `return` in this situation.

Comment: True, as ruby implicitly returns the last statement of a method. However, I added these here for clarity. ;)